# Output of this character array java program

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to change the information in create a new character array of Str without the whitespaces. However, I cant succeed in doing sp

I dont know why the output says:

Haveaniceday
Have  a nice   day

instead of:

Haveaniceday
Haveaniceday

```
import java.util.*;
class DelExtraSpace
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        char c[],s[];
        String str; 
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        str = "Have  a nice   day";

        c = str.toCharArray();
        s = new char [c.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
        {
            if(!Character.isSpaceChar(c[i]))
            {
                System.out.print(c[i]);
                s[i] = c[i]; // I want the value of c[i] to be assigned to s[i] only when c[i] is not a whitespace
            }               
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int j = 0; j < s.length; j++)
            System.out.print(s[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your quesiton is not clear. What is your code supposed to do and what is the output you expect ?

Comment: I was expecting that  
  
        System.out.println();  
        for(int j = 0; j < s.length; j++)  
            System.out.print(s[j]);  
  
Should have printed:  
Haveaniceday  
Haveaniceday

Comment: Sorry I am new here and have some issues with formatting my replies

Comment: Post code as an edit to your question since code does not format well in comments.

Comment: I ran your code here http://ideone.com/PN8BeJ and it appears to output your expected output.

Comment: Isn't that strange jdphenix? I am getting the output that I expected with this code at the link you gave: http://ideone.com/PN8BeJ. However, the code given by curiosu works fine on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you are wondering why `s` is not changed.

In this case, try this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    char c[], s[];
    String str;
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    str = "Have  a nice   day";

    c = str.toCharArray();
    s = new char[c.length];

    int ii = 0;                                 // ADDED
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (!Character.isSpaceChar(c[i])) {
            System.out.print(c[i]);
            s[ii] = c[i];                       // CHANGED                              
            ii++;                               // ADDED
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++)
        System.out.print(s[j]);
}
```

I added 3 comments for the modified/added lines.

Now the output should be:

```
Haveaniceday
Haveaniceday
```

---

**Short explanation**

Obviously, `s` will be shorter than `c` (because it doesn't contain those spaces).
This is why you need a new contor (`ii`) instead of `i`.

- `ii` takes values from 0 to 11
- `i` takes values from 0 to 17

> ```
> ii -> i
> 0 -> 0
> 1 -> 1
> 2 -> 2
> 3 -> 3
>                  // 4 and 5 are indexes for spaces => they are ignored
> 4 -> 6           
>                  // 7 is index for space => it is ignored
> 5 -> 8            
> 6 -> 9
> 7 -> 10
> 8 -> 11
>                  // 12, 13 and 14 are indexes for spaces => they are ignored
> 9 -> 15
> 10 -> 16
> 11 -> 17
> ```

E.g.: When 4 and 5 were ignored, `ii` was not incremented because we don't need "gaps" in the final array, only the values that are not space.

Comment: Some explanation would be nice, I suppose.

Comment: Yes Curiosu, if you could also explain why I didnt get the desired output with my code on my machine but on http://ideone.com/PN8BeJ i get the same output that I was looking for